# changing indicator holder background color in AndroidImageSlider

Tags: java, android

how to change image indicator holder background color:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:background="#133"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
    sliderShow = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);

    textSliderView.image(file_maps.get(name));

    sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **PagerIndicator** after **SliderLayout** in your xml in **RelativeLayout**

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
    custom:auto_cycle="true" />

<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/banner_slider_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:selected_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:unselected_color="@color/iconsLight"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/dividerDark"
    style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Indicator" />
```

**style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Indicator"**

```
<style name="AndroidImageSlider_Indicator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="shape">oval</item>
    <item name="padding_left">3dp</item>
    <item name="padding_right">3dp</item>
    <item name="padding_top">4dp</item>
    <item name="padding_bottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="selected_width">8dp</item>
    <item name="selected_height">8dp</item>
    <item name="unselected_width">6dp</item>
    <item name="unselected_height">6dp</item>
</style>
```

Java Code

```
SliderLayout sliderLayout = (SliderLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.banner_slider);
PagerIndicator pagerIndicator = (PagerIndicator) rootView.findViewById(R.id.banner_slider_indicator);
DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getContext());

    defaultSliderView
        .description(name)
        .image(slider_covers.get(name))
        .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

    sliderLayout.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
    sliderLayout.setCustomIndicator(pagerIndicator);
```

Comment: can u send the style too (@style/AndroidImageSlider_Indicator)

Comment: added my style, modify as u need.

Comment: we are adding additional Indicator holder #hafiz Muneeb but its not my problem.plz see this link once(https://ibb.co/kzLLfa)

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not clear. Please explain your problem clearly

Comment: plz follow the link(ibb.co/kzLLfa), here we have transparent one and color dark gray one i want to change transparent color one or removing that one

Comment: exactly i want this ouput..plz can u share ur file

Comment: u can see my complete code here https://ibb.co/hEKz6F    atleast tell what wrong i did compairing to ur file

Comment: edited my code, try and let me know if it works for you

Comment: i got the solution bro...just removing the custom indiactor:)

Answer (score 0):

Shall you try this?

```
textSliderView.getView().findViewById(R.id.description_layout).setBackgroundColor(<your_color>);
```

Comment: am using (Above link)this...its working fine but we dont required background color...can u help me plz

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/render_type_text.xml 
description_layout has sliderlayout.